# How do Padrino sub apps work?

Tags: rack, code-organization, padrino

OK, so let's say I have two different projects.  Each are are related categorically, but different databases and such.

Example (projects):

```
Project Management
Help Desk Management
```

A user could be a member of either project (or both).  But I want to be able to tie them together.  So that either could be stand alone.  Or, a help desk ticket could be tied to a project, etc.

I would have one user base.

So, how would I structure this?  Would users be a sub-app of both?  Would I have some type of "launcher" app that would contain these as two sub-apps?

Like:

```
Launcher App
    Projects
    Help Desk
    Users
```